# Question about the redundance in DCGAN training

Tags: gan

I don't understand the necessity of the redundance in the training of DCGAN. So a classical DSGAN training procedure is like this:
[image]

My questions:

1. Can I remove step (7)-(8) and and reuse the fake images of (4) to compute the generator loss?
2. If so, can I further reuse the result of $D(G(z))$? i.e.
   Generate fake images -> compute generator loss and discriminator loss using the same $D(G(z))$ values -> update generator -> update discriminator